# ERROR: System.Environment.SpecialFolder' does not contain a definition for 'CommonApplicationData'

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have the code to save a file in a folder in directory

```
string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy.HH-mm-ss");
                var file = File.Create("Owe-Data.txt" + timestamp);

                var com = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase + timestamp + @"\Data" + file;

               MessageBox.Show(com);
               if (!Directory.Exists(com))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(com);
                }
               using (var sw = new StreamWriter(com))
                {

                    sw.WriteLine(InputData);

                }

            }
```

i Displayed COM it gives path bt i cant see the Data folder or Owe-Data file at that path
Anybody can tell why this happening, or should i save the Data folder in current directory where this prgram running? bt i dnt know how to reach that path. Any solutions ??
Working on windows phone 5, visual studio 2008 .NET framwork 2.0

Comment: Which platform? Version of .Net etc

Comment: using visual studio 2008

Comment: May I know the Windows version you are using?

Comment: Close your visual studio and run it as admin....it should solve the prob

Comment: @rapsalands I assume you're joking. How that will help? and why?

Comment: @user3012548 I asked WPF or Windows phone? What framework version of .Net? 2.0? 4.0?

Comment: @Sriram: I am very much aware about the platforms to crack joke....need not educate. To me it looks like he is facing the problem with permissions. Windows 7 points towards C:\Program Data for CommonApplicationData. It is basically folder for multi user and does not belong to a single user. And hence he is not able to edit it. He need to have admin rights in order to do so.

Comment: @rapsalands Did you read the error? It is a compile time error!

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: `but when running the program it gives error `. Does it mean Compile error?

Comment: @rapsalands `System.Environment.SpecialFolder' does not contain a definition for 'CommonApplicationData'` Do you think this error will be thrown at runtime?

Comment: I does not matter what I think. It all matters what OP writes and give info about.

Comment: @sriram sakthvel: its windows phon and .net framwork 2.0

Comment: @rapsalands: u r right brother, i tried on admin mode but prblm not solved

Comment: @user3012548: Hmmm....I am trying to do the same in my system. Its working fine and I can also see the folder created

Comment: yes its a compile time error @sriram

Comment: hmmmm ok i also gonna check it on different machine @rapsalands

Comment: that folder doesn't exist on Windows Phone

Comment: @Xaruth: then what i should do ?

Comment: don't use this folder (it doesn't exist), and take a look to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As per the **Exceptions** section of [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),the above exception is thrown when

> **ArgumentException**  -------  folder is not a member of System.Environment.SpecialFolder.

It means the `OS` where you are running this command does not have `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` as one of the special folder.

**For knowledge,**
`Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` is the most common one. This folder holds per-user, non-temporary application-specific data, other than user documents. A common example would be a settings or configuration file.

`Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` is similar, but shared across users. You could use this to store document templates, for instance.

`Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` is a non-roaming alternative for `ApplicationData`. As such, you'd never store important data there. However, because it's non-roaming it is a good location for temporary files, caches, etcetera. It's typically on a local disk.

**I think the problem may be that** `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` is common and shared between different users and the `user`  with which you have logged in is not having `rights to access the folder` or the `Visual Studio` has not been started in `Admin` mode.

**EDIT** Look at [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and try to add a manual registry `Common AppData`  defined in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\`

Comment: you give v well solution plz tel me 1 thing can i manually create commonApplicationData a member of Environment.SpecialFolder

Comment: As per my knowledge, it is not possible to manually create commonApplicationData a member of Environment.SpecialFolder

Comment: @user3012548 just try to add a manual registry as mentioned in link and see if the problem is solved

Comment: problem solved by using var com = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd") + @"\Owe-Data"; instead of Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) it does not have any folder like commonappdata for windows mobile

Comment: @user3012548 you should clearly mention that you are using windows phone where you are facing this problem

Comment: my mistake feel sory for that

Answer (score 0):

**Given you are asking about a .NET Windows Phone application as per the tags**

I think your problem is that a .NET Windows Phone application does not have direct access to the file system; it can only access [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) this is by design.

I would quote a Microsoft source for this but I can't seem to find one!

**EDIT**
See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) from MSDN